# Would moving away from urban areas affect client acquisition for a freelance designer?

Tags: business, client-relations, freelance

I am an entry level designer contemplating a move to the country. This move would give me lots more time to work on my portfolio and develop my skills, but also isolate me from the more white-collar communities.

I would be reliant on marketing myself online, at least for the first two years. Or I could stick where I am at, which is already country-ish, and have a little less time to concentrate, and therefore the possibility for in-person contacts and community.

Is a move to the country a poor idea?

I do have an art background and could simultaneously work on my design and develop some fine art to help market my non-traditional self.

**Would moving to a rural area affect my client acquisition, and subsequently, profitability?**

If yes, are there any ways I could counteract the loss of business?

Comment: "A move to the country" is pretty broad. Are we talking about a town of 2,500 people or are we talking about living miles from another human? And how far from the nearest metro area? Might also help to know what kind of design you plan on doing.

Answer (score 5):

Being closely situated to the culture you're trying to be part of - whether it is a music scene, an art collective, or a social club - is essential, and being a professional designer is no different. To get clients, you will need to network - and there is a good chance that the network you seek will be based in an urban area.

Networking is certainly a lot easier in the city, where there are coffee shops, restaurants and even pubs where you could meet potential or existing clients. There is a lot of potential to meet clients at events like design meet-ups or creative discussions - check out your local area and see what's happening where you are (or hope to be living). Where I live, these are usually hosted by creative organisations and universities, all of which are based in the city (but this doesn't apply to everywhere of course).

It will also depend on the type of clients and industries that you're targetting, and what kind of design work you will be doing, as has been noted already. I know a few Fine Art graduates from my university days who relocated to the country to produce their art and work on their skills, but even they need to venture into the city to sell their work - travel costs, obviously, affecting their bottom line. It all adds up!

I hope this helps.